# How do I get a spring-boot controller to work when using the maven assembly plugin instead of the spring boot maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, controller, maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following simple structure

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        me
          Main.java
          controller
            TestController.java
    webapp
      something.html
pom.xml
```

I then bundle everything using the maven-assembly-plugin like this...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ${main.class}
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run with `java -cp target\*;props com.me.Main` everything boots and I can access `something.html` but when I try to hit the controller...

```
@Controller
@EnableAsync
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    @Async
    public String getInfo(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

With the address `http://localhost:8080/test` I get a 404. How do I get the controller to work? The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is not an option because I can not run it like `java -cp` only `java -jar` and I need to add properties files to the classpath.

Comment: The source directory should be `src/main/java` instead of `src/java`.

Comment: Sorry it is that was a typo @JFabianMeier

Comment: Why using maven-assembly-plugin instead of spring-boot-maven plugin? Technically a spring boot jar is more than an ueber jar with all dependencies in there... there bootstrap part of it etc. which you have not created via maven-assembly-plugin..?